# Есть ли torrent client на flash или есть возможность реализовать это?

Tags: flash, torrent

Есть ли torrent client на flash или есть возможность реализовать это?

Comment: Зачем вам это?

Comment: Это отдельный вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Исходного кода для торрент клиента в прямом доступе нет
- Реализовать можно: а) возложив обязанности закачки на сервер, флеш на сайте использовав только для отображения процесса и сохранения файла на клиенте б) как air приложение (реализовав торрент протокол на ас3+socket) веб в таком случае отпадает

Для веб флеша очень суровые условия безопасности установки соединения по socket (как и по http). 
1) Каждый подключаемый IP host должен высылать специальный подтверждающий crossdomain файл.
2) Веб версия флеш плеера не имеет возможности прослушивать порт для принятия внешних соединений.

Answer (score 0):

Нету, и нет возможности, и [вот здесь](http://osflash.org/pipermail/osflash_osflash.org/2007-August/014099.html) написано, почему.

ps:// [подобный вопрос на stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163355/flash-torrent-client)